# aspx.cs need explain to me

Tags: asp.net

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

and some1 explain it to me what do all this usings do please?

im really struggling to find anything on the internet 
thanks

Comment: I find it hard to believe that an internet search yielded nothing. http://www.bing.com/search?q=.net+what+is+a+code+behind+file&src=ie9tr 
   Or this one http://www.bing.com/search?q=.net+what+are+using+statments&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=.net+what+are+using+statments&sc=1-29&sp=-1&sk=

Comment: Actually they do nothing (as they are). If you stay an look them you do not going to learn anything, try some other way, take some lessons, go to a school for programmers, find some programmer to teach you the basic, buy some books for the basic.

Answer (score 2):

They are namespaces that are imported. It is similar to `#include<stdio.h>` in C